# How to connect to Open X server from Windows client?

Tags: windows, x11, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'd searched on Google, but I don't found any software for Windows, which provide way to connect to Open X server from Windows. Can you give me, please, any programs, which can connect to Open X server from Windows(Windows 10, if neccessary)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? An X Server provides a windowing system for its clients, therefore if you want to connect to a Unix/Linux machine, run UI programs there and display them on a Windows machine, you actually want an X Server for Windows. If I remember correctly, last time I did that (a while ago), I used https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ Have you tried that?

Comment: @Luis I mean connecting to X server with port 6000 (not SSH tunnel), just direct connection